# Questions about installing a 3-way dimmer switch

Tags: switch, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

I am trying to replace a 3-way switch from Legrand with a dimmer switch from FEIT. I have attached a simple drawing here.
Before I make the change, I would like someone to help confirm the electrical connection.
T1 -> AC_L
T2 -> YL_RD
HOT -> LOAD
GND -> GND
Neutral -> AC_N (The neutral wire is not used in the 3-way switch but I have access to it).

Thank you so much for your help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The 2 3-way switches on the first row are in the same wall plate cover. And I am trying to replace one of them with a dimmer switch.

Comment: What model is the dimmer you are using? Also, what do you want to do with the circuit controlled by the other switch on the existing yoke?

Comment: The current 3-way switch is https://www.legrand.us/wiring-devices/light-switches-and-dimmers/residential-switches/radiant-15a-3-way-switch-white/p/tm873w.

Comment: The Feit switch is https://www.feit.com/product/smart-wi-fi-dimmer/

Comment: Can a dimmer switch coexist with a 3-way on/off switch? I don't have any plan with that switch and prefer not to replace it with another dimmer switch unless it has to be...

Comment: Is replacing the existing box with a larger box an option?

Comment: Wait a minute... "The 2 3-way switches on the first row are in the same wall plate cover." Does this mean you've got two switches right next to each other that both control the same set of lights in a 3-way switch configuration (either switch will toggle the same set of lights), or does this mean that you're wanting to control 2 independently 3-way controlled set of lights with the one new switch? Is the one new switch also a 3-way?

Comment: Hi Freeman, the 3-way switches on the first row are just 2 switches (A and B) work independently (control different lights in the room). What I want to do is replace one of them with the dimmer switch (C) (in a 3-way configuration). 
For example, A turns on/off Light Alpha, B turns on/off Light Beta. I want to replace A with C so that C can turn on/off Alpha ( plus all the features come with the dimmer switch). And switch B to remain the same.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, Unfortunately, that's not an option...

Comment: A picture of the actual wiring of the switch to be replaced (turn off power, remove the cover plate, pull the switch out of the box _without_ disconnecting any wiring, show all connections and where they go back into the box), as well as a picture of or link to the instructions for the new switch, would be most helpful.

Comment: @FreeMan I have uploaded the pictures here. Thank you! 
This is the link to the installation guide of the new switch. https://www.feit.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Smart_Dimmer_Installation_Guide.pdf

Comment: Even though the FEIT Electric switch gives you 2 spaces for a ground wire, it is a code violation to use a device as a method to splice ground wires. **It must be pigtailed** so that the ground remains continuous even if the device is removed.   I'm really surprised UL/ETL didn't require them to blank over one of the two holes.

Comment: @TheoRen can you post photos looking into the backs of all boxes involved please?

Answer (score 1):

### 3-way dimmers/smart switches don't work like that.

You are expecting this operation to be a "drop-in replacement" - where there would be a direct 1:1 mapping between the old 3-way switch wires and the new switch wires. That's not really how these things work.

There are at least 5 different ways to wire a traditional 3-way circuit.  As such, the topology of the wiring of the existing circuit must be researched. Only then can it be determined which location is possible for the dimmer master.

You heard that right - you don't get to decide where the dimmer master is put.  You are at the mercy of the wall wiring.

So the next step here is to trace out the entire circuit and determine how the cables are routed.  From there, we can look at the wiring options.